# Hadoop/Spark for build large analytics report

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I know nothing about distributed processing engines, so it's pretty hard to understand does it suit for my needs.

I have a huge table in relation database, users work with it every day (crud operations and search).

And now there is a new task - have a possibility to build huge aggregate report for a one-two year period on demand. And do it fast.
All this table records for last two years are too big to fit in memory, so I should split computations into chunks, right?

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so my question is,
does distributed processing systems like Hadoop are suit for this kind of tasks?

Answer (score 0):

It may.
The non Hadoop way would be to create semi aggregate report which you can use for other aggregate.
I.e using 30 daily aggregate to create 1 monthly aggregate.

In some cases it may not be possible so you can pull the data to your spark cluster or such and do your aggregate. 
Usually relational database won't give you the data locality features so you can move the data to some nosql database like Cassandra or hbase or elasticsearch. 
Also a big key question is do you want the answer to be real time? Unless you go through some effort like job server etc spark or Hadoop jobs are usually batch job. Means you submit the job and get the answer later (spark streaming is an exception.)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to use approach with pre-aggregated reports, because there are some aggregated parameters from user input and anytime some new data can be migrated from legacy systems.

No, there is absolutely no need in real-time, report should be generated asynchronously. Does it mean that Hadoop way is the best approach in this case?